# Meaning of this statement in java and spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am new to Java and spring batch can someone help me with what does this statement imply

```
return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    };
```

Comment: It's a lambda expression. The return type of the method must be a functional interface.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe rewriting it, helps understanding (not using correct Types/Classes here since unknown to me):

```
BiFunction<Contribution, Context, RepeatStatus> function = 
    (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    };
return function;
```

---

Without using Lambda, would be *similar* to creating a class like

```
class MyFunction implements BiFunction<Contribution, Context, RepeatStatus> {
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus apply(Contribution contribution, Context chunkContext) {
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

and, the `return` would be like

```
    return new MyFunction();
```

<sub>not tested, no IDE used; 
this is not intended to be a working code/example; 
assuming lots of types here (`Contribution`, `Context`, `BiFunction`), original is probably using different classes/names</sub>